# Непонятная ошибка

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int n, m, sum = 0;

cin >> n;

for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{           
        m = 5 * (pow(10, i));
        sum += m;                         
}
cout << sum;
system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, где тут ошибка и почему программа так странно себя ведет???
Проблема: Ввожу N = 2, выводит 50 (все верно). Ввожу N = 3, выводит 549. Помогите мне понять, что за 549 он выводит?! Откуда он берет его?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну тут вы сами должны понимать, что вытворяете...Так, в случае с введенной двойкой, этот цикл:

```
 for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
 {           
    m = 5 * (pow(10, i));
    sum += m;                         
 }
```

Выполнится только один раз. В результате переменная Sum будет содержать следующее значение:

```
Sum = 5(pow(10,1)) // 5 * (10 в первой степени).
```

В случае с тройкой цикл выполнится два раза. Результат:

```
sum = 0
Первая итерация - sum += 5(10,1);  //sum=50
Вторая итерация - sum += 5(10,2);  //sum=500
```

**P.S**  Я не знаю, что вас может пугать и откуда вытекают непонятности...смысл параметров функции `pow` вы, вроде бы, не путаете.

---

**UPD:**

Функция **POW-математическая** функция C++, работающая с точными значениями. Поэтому, её параметры - числа с плавающей точкой! Смотрите код, все сами поймете:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
double n, m, sum = 0;

cin >> n;

for(double i = 1.0; i < n; i+=1)
{           
        m = ((pow(10.0, i)) * 5);
        cout<<m<<endl;
        sum += m;                         
}
cout << sum;
system("PAUSE");
}
```

Именно поэтому у вас и терялась единичка =)

Comment: @Asen, да, и 50 + 500, должно быть, разве нет? А это делает 550, но не 549 же! Никак не могу понять в чем дело

Comment: Разобрался. Смотрите дополнение =)

Comment: @Asen, вот этого реально не ожидал. Спасибо за помощь!